# How to Block Python ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python

I have a threadpool that i'd like to limit not only the max number of workers but the max number of jobs that can be submitted to the threadpool at once. The reason for limiting the jobs is because the jobs are generated much quicker than the threadpool workers can execute and it can exhaust all available memory quickly.

How i'd like to interface with a "blocking" threadpool:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
  for i in range(100_000_000):
    executor.submit(do_work, i, block=True)
```

But `block=True` is not a thing on the executor.

Is there a blocking threadpool I can use which will block submission to the queue if the number of jobs in queue is at max_size? If not, what would be the best way to implement a blocking threadpool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L118), there seems to be a relatively non-intrusive way to define one yourself:

```
class BlockingThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, *, queue_size=0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._work_queue = queue.SimpleQueue(queue_size)
```

All this does is replace the unbounded work queue with a bounded one. Calls to `submit` will now block on their call to `self._work_queue.put` when the queue gets too full.

(This definition assumes you'll use keywords arguments, even though `ThreadPoolExecutor.__init__` does not require them.)

All the standard warnings about modifying private class details apply, but this is a pretty minimal change. As long as no future versions of `ThreadPoolExecutor` change the name of the attribute or switch to a class with an incompatible interface with `SimpleQueue`, it should work fine.

Comment: That's perfect- thanks!

Comment: It seems that `SimpleQueue` does not have a `queue_size` parameter form limiting its size. You can use a `Queue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, what kind of function are you trying to parallelize?

In many cases a ThreadPool might not be what you want since due to the GIL only one thread can manipulate python objects at a time.
In that case you will have to use multiprocessing to get actual benefit out of parallelizing.

If not then coroutines (asyncio) might be a good fit for your problem as well which could avoid your problem.

Comment: It's net IO blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that doesn't assume the internals of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and also limits jobs a bit more intuitively.

```
class BoundedThreadPoolExecutor(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):
  def __init__(self, *args, max_pending_items, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._semaphor = threading.Semaphore(max_pending_items)

  def submit(self, fn, /, *args, **kwargs):
    self._semaphor.acquire()
    f = super().submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    f.add_done_callback(lambda _: self._semaphor.release())
    return f
```

Documentation on [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore).

If you replace `self._work_queue` with a fixed size `Queue`  like @chepner's answer, the limit for the max number of jobs that can be submitted is actually `max_workers` + `max queue size` because each of the workers will pop from the queue to start work. Which works and is still bounded! But it wasn't obvious to me that that was the bound. [Link](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-isnt-this-boundedthreadpoolexecutor-bounded-as-expected/38428?u=alexbeloi) to question I had about this on python users forum.